# Entity Embed module not working as expected

Tags: 8, entities

I am wanting to use the [Entity Embed](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_embed) module, and have installed this an it's dependent, Embed module, in Drupal 8.

There are no errors in the log, nor any javascript errors.

When I go to create the Entity Embed button, I get the follow UI feedback:
[image]
Is there something I need to do to allow entities to be embedable?

**Installed Modules:**
Here is a list of all modules I have installed.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have the Embed module enabled, but not Entity Embed itself.

Embed is just the underlying API/framework on which Entity Embed and Url Embed build.